# Shouldn't the electric flux formula include multiple angle rotations?

Tags: electromagnetism, gauss-law

The electric flux formula is given by $Φ_Α = \pmb Ε \cdot \pmb A = EAcosφ$ as shown in the picture below:

[image: electric flux]

However only a vertical tilt of angle $φ$ is considered. What if there is a horizontal tilt of angle $θ$? Shouldn't the formula then become $EAcosφcosθ$?

Comment: $\phi$ is the angle between the electric field and the plane, no matter how the plane is tilted. If you want to see a "horizontal" tilt, just turn your head and look at the page again.

Comment: But if I turn the page, both the field and the plane are titled horizontally, thereby the effect is zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any dot product $\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} = u*v*$cos$\phi$. Where $u$ is the magnitude or, colloquially, the length of the vector $\vec{u}$. Additionally, the angle $\phi$ is the angle between the vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$.

Thus,

$$\vec{E} \cdot \vec{A} = E*A*\text{cos}\phi$$

where $\phi$ is simply the angle between your vectors $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{A}$. Now, if you tilt your surface $A$, you change the direction of $\vec{A}$, and therefore you change the angle $\phi$. Any tilt of the plane $A$ is accounted for.

Here is a more complete answer:

Electric flux is given by

$$\Phi = \oint_S{\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{A}}$$

where $S$ is the surface you're integrating over and $d$$\vec{A}$ $=$ $\hat{n} * dA$.

Thus,

$$\Phi = \oint_S{\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{A}} = \oint_S{\vec{E} \cdot \hat{n}*dA}$$

If you haven't seen this form of flux, all the equation says is "at every point on the surface through which you are computing flux, find the component of the electric field parallel to the surface normal vector and add all of these components up." Intuitively, you are literally adding how much electric field "pierces" through the surface of interst.

Observing that $\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} = |u||v|$cos$\phi$,

$$\Phi = \oint_S{|\vec{E}||\hat{n}|\text{cos}\phi *dA} = \oint_S{E*\text{cos}\phi *dA}$$

Where, crucially, $\phi$ is the angle between the vectors $\vec{E}$ and $\hat{n}$. Thus, the angle $\phi$ does not correspond to any particular direction of tilt. *It corresponds exactly to the angle between the surface normal $\hat{n}$ and the electric field at that point.*

Comment: Ok, now I realize that the angle $φ$ is the angle between the two vectors. I was erroneously visualizing the problem as having  separate vertical and a horizontal rotations.

Comment: Yep :)! Glad you got it figured out! @Nick

Answer (score 0):

Changing $\phi$ would correspond to rotating the surface around an axis parallel with the electric field.<sup>1</sup>  This would not actually change the amount of flux through a surface of a fixed area, since the whole setup is rotationally symmetric about this axis.  In other words, the flux is independent of $\phi$.

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm using $\phi$ as the OP implicitly defined it in the question they wrote, not as it is shown in the diagram they included.

Comment: I do not understand how they are parallel. I'm visualizing the field as straight lines in space (three dimensions). Clearly, if we have two parallel lines, rotating any of them in any direction at an angle besides $π$ radians , would make them nonparallel.

Comment: I fixed the angle names.